# Why is 'Measure-Object -InputObject $foo' different from '$foo | Measure-Object' in PowerShell?

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting

I have six .txt files in a directory. So, I create a variable thus:

```
$foo = gci -Name *.txt
```

`$foo` is now an array of six strings. In my case I have

```
PS > $foo
Extensions.txt
find.txt
found_nots.txt
output.txt
proteins.txt
text_files.txt

PS > $foo.gettype()
IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array

PS > $foo.Count
6
```

I'd like to measure that object, so I pass it to [Measure-Object](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849965.aspx):

```
PS > $foo | Measure-Object

Count    : 6
Average  :
Sum      :
Maximum  :
Minimum  :
Property :
```

That's what I was expecting. However, I might also pass `$foo` like this:

```
PS> Measure-Object -InputObject $foo

Count    : 1
Average  :
Sum      :
Maximum  :
Minimum  :
Property :
```

That's not what I was expecting. What's going on here?

Comment: Just a note: $foo is not an array of strings. It is an array of FileSystemInfos. Try `$foo[0].getTYpe()`

Comment: I'm definitely getting strings. `$foo = gci -Name *.txt` followed by `$foo[0].gettype().Name` gives `String`

Comment: However, If I do `$foo = gci -Filter *.txt` instead then `$foo[0].gettype().Name` gives `FileInfo`

Comment: The above were on PowerShell 2, in case its different in other versions.

Comment: I see what is going on. `-Name` is a switch that tells `gci` to only return the name. The `*.txt` is actually `-Path *.txt`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you execute:

```
$foo | measure-object
```

PowerShell automatically unrolls collections/arrays and passes each element down the pipeline to the next stage.

When you execute:

```
measure-object -inputobject $foo
```

The cmdlet does not internally unroll the collection.  This is often times helpful if you want to inspect the collection without having PowerShell do its automatic unrolling.  BTW the same thing applies to Get-Member.  If you want to see the members on the "collection" instead of each individual element do this:

```
get-member -inputobject $foo
```

One way to simulate this in the pipeline case is:

```
,$foo | Get-Member
```

This will wrap whatever foo is (collection in this case) in another collection with one element.  When PowerShell automatically unrolls that to send elements down the pipeline, the only element is `$foo` which gets sent down the pipeline.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know about this since I'm still rather wet behind the ears regarding PowerShell.  I've now read the documentation via `get-help about_pipelines` and the relevant part of the text is "When you pipe multiple objects to a command,
 Windows PowerShell sends the objects to the command one at a time. When you use a command parameter, the objects are sent as a single array object."

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell may be able to help you out here. Let's take a look at `Get-Help Measure-Object -full` and check out that parameter.

```
-InputObject <psobject>
    Specifies the objects to be measured. Enter a variable that contains 
    the objects, or type a command or expression that gets the objects.

    Required?                    false
    Position?                    named
    Default value
    Accept pipeline input?       true (ByValue)
    Accept wildcard characters?  false
```

Pipeline input is accepted by value, so that means that it counts each line of `$foo` and tallies them. For what it is worth, all of the [example usages on Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849965.aspx) and in the [Get-Help](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849696.aspx) reference use pipeline input for this parameter.